# Selenium : Unable to identify object using data provider

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Beginner in this space, appreciate your help on the problem!

I'm trying to script a path

Login
create new user
log out

Login method works fine
Create user is dependent on Login method to be completed, using data providers and post login to create new user

Issue is after logging in the elements/objects in create user class are not identified. I have tried it using different element finders and browsers. Appreciate if you help around

Project Structure is 
Project
Package1
 Logindataprovider.class
 newaccountDataProvider.class
Package2
 LoginpageObjects.class
 NewAccountPageObjects.class
Package3
 LoginTestscripts.class
 NewAccountTestScript.class

LoginTestscripts- Class

```
LoginPageObjects LgnObj = new LoginPageObjects();
@Test(groups = { "Logingroup1" }, dataProvider = "LoginCred", dataProviderClass = LoginDataProviders.class)
public void mytest(String DDUname, String DDpwd,String ExpLoginPage, int Browsertype) {

        LgnObj.setBrowser(Browsertype);

        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoginDataProviders.class);
        log.info("Login To application method");

        LgnObj.init();

        // Login page assertion actual values
        String LoginPageAssertactual = LgnObj.LoginPageAssertionActual();

        //Login page assertion
        Assert.assertEquals(LoginPageAssertactual, ExpLoginPage);

        //login to application
        LogginCommonProcess(DDUname, DDpwd, LgnObj);

    }

    public void LogginCommonProcess(String DDUname, String DDpwd,
            LoginPageObjects LgnObj) {

        LgnObj.enterUserName(DDUname);
        LgnObj.enterPassword(DDpwd);

        LgnObj.Loginbtn();
        LgnObj.enterPIN();
        LgnObj.CompanyName();

    }

Logindataprovider- Class
public class LoginPageObjects {

    WebDriver driver;

    public void setBrowser(int type) {
        if (type == 1) {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } else if (type == 2) {
            String path = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("chromedriver.exe")
                    .getPath();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path);
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else if (type == 3) {
            String path = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("IEDriverServer.exe")
                    .getPath();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", path);
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }
    }

    public void init() {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to("https://test2.qatest.com/Login.aspx");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public String LoginPageAssertionActual() {
        String LoginPageAssertionact = driver.findElement(By.tagName("h1"))
                .getText();
        return LoginPageAssertionact;
    }

    public void enterUserName(String DDUname) {

        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MainContent_usernameField")).sendKeys(
                DDUname);
    }

    public void enterPassword(String DDpwd) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MainContent_passwordField")).sendKeys(
                DDpwd);
    }

New User- page object
public class NewUser {

    WebDriver driver;

    public void setup() {
        System.out.println("Start here");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.navigate().to("https://test2.directorsdesk.com/Login.aspx");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void setBrowser(int type) {
        if (type == 1) {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } else if (type == 2) {
            String path = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("chromedriver.exe")
                    .getPath();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path);
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else if (type == 3) {
            String path = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("IEDriverServer.exe")
                    .getPath();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", path);
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        } else if (type == 4) {
            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            cap.setBrowserName("chrome");
            cap.setVersion("38");
            cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
            try {
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(
                        "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // log erro unable to access remote system, running in local
                // firefox
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            }
        }
    }

    **public void ManageSystem() {
        driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Manage System")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Manage System")).click();

    }**

public class NewAccount {

    @Test(dataProvider = "UserDetails", dataProviderClass = LoginDataProviders.class, dependsOnGroups = "Logingroup1")
    public void CreateNewAccount(String Emailid, String Firstname,
            String Lastname, String PrimaryEmailid, int browserType) {

        NewUser NewUserObj = new NewUser();
        NewUserObj.setBrowser(browserType);
        **NewUserObj.ManageSystem();** // Fails here
        NewUserObj.UserAccounts();
        NewUserObj.NewUserAccount();
        NewUserObj.Emailid(Emailid);
        NewUserObj.UserFirstname(Firstname);
        NewUserObj.UserLastname(Lastname);
        NewUserObj.PrimaryEmai(PrimaryEmailid);
        NewUserObj.SaveAccountSettings();

        LoginPageObjects LgnPgObj = new LoginPageObjects();
        LgnPgObj.Logout();
        LgnPgObj.closeBrowser();

    }
```

Comment: Is there any solution you found on this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
public void entityFieldIsEntered(String field, String value)  {
    WebElement valueElem = new SharedDriver().findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[text()='" + field
            + ":'])[2]/parent::*/span/input"));
    valueElem.sendKeys(new CharSequence[] { value });

}
```

assuming you are using input wrapper in your html. This code search for text label on the screen, then goes to its parent and navigate to input field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use multiple page objects in one test, you will need to share the same driver between those page objects.
Try creating a separate setupDriver class and have each page object take a driver parameter to be constructed.
At the beginning of each test setup the driver, then pass in the driver as you create each object.